# why are some cygwin symlinks not visible from a cmd.exe session

Tags: scala, jvm, cygwin, symlink

**Summary:**

In the most recent (Sept. 2020) version of 64-bit cygwin, the symlinks in the `/bin/` and `/lib` directories have puzzling features, and seem to differ from any of the various other documented symlinks.  The questions are:

1. why are they hidden from CMD.EXE, but visible elsewhere, unlike
   other symlink types
2. is it possible to create symlinks with identical features? if so, how?

**TL;DR**
See @matzeri's answer: the SYSTEM attribute is set on `/bin/awk`, making it invisible to CMD.EXE sessions.

The symlinks below `/bin` and `/lib` seem to be one of the two types of "default cygwin symlinks" described here:

> The default symlinks created by Cygwin are either special reparse
> points shared with WSL on Windows 10, or plain files containing a
> magic cookie followed by the path to which the link points. The
> reparse point is used on NTFS, the plain file on almost any other
> filesystem.
> see [symbolic links](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#pathnames-symlinks)

However, all of the symlinks below `/bin` have the SYSTEM attribute set, and most of the symlinks below `/lib` don't.  I don't know how was I able to create a symlink with a magic cookie on NTFS.

**Below is the long version of the question**

There are multiple types of symlinks under cygwin.   Other questions explain their history, describe their differences, and show how to create them, etc.   For example:

[check the difference of symlink type in cygwin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24222591/check-the-difference-of-symlink-type-in-cygwin)

Here's a discussion of some of the history and problems with symlinks on windows:

[Symlinks on the mounted Windows directories are not compatible with native](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/353)

As described, there are shortcuts, junction points, and symlinks, all of which are visible from a CMD.EXE session, as demonstrated.

However, under my 64-bit cygwin installation, there is another type that I can't find any explanation for.   A number of them appear below `/bin`, `/lib`, and perhaps other places.  The main characteristic that distinguishes them from the other 3 is that they aren't visible from a CMD.EXE session.

Here's one example:
If I attempt to list 'awk' via CMD.EXE from the /bin directory, the file seems to not exist:

```sh
$ cd /bin

$ cmd.exe /c dir awk

 Volume in drive C is opt
 Volume Serial Number is D0C8-EA58

 Directory of C:\cygwin64\bin

File Not Found
```

Here's what it looks to to `ls`:

```sh
$ ls -l awk
lrwxrwxrwx 1 philwalk None 8 May 14 12:26 awk -> gawk.exe
```

But most symlinks, in my experience, ARE visible from a CMD.EXE session.   Let's create a symlink for testing:

```sh
$ CYGWIN=winsymlinks:nativestrict # make sure we don't create an old-style symlink
$ ln -s `which ls.exe` ls-link
$ cmd.exe /c dir ls-link
 Volume in drive C is opt
 Volume Serial Number is D0C8-EA58

 Directory of C:\opt\ue

2020-09-03  13:12    <SYMLINK>      ls-link [C:\cygwin64\bin\ls.exe]
               1 File(s)              0 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  295,290,556,416 bytes free
```

This shows that CMD.EXE can see this type of symlink.

It appears that all symlinks can be dereferenced like this:

```
$ cygpath -w `which awk`
C:\cygwin64\bin\gawk.exe
```

So can a windows-based program dereference them? Can it see them at all? Because they aren't visible to CMD.EXE, I would have guessed that they aren't visible to any other windows (i.e., non-cygwin) program.

Here's a scala script, `deref.sc`, that will test these questions:

```scala
#!/usr/bin/env scala

import java.nio.file._

for( posixPath <- args ){
  val cyg = cygpath(posixPath)
  val windows = Paths.get(posixPath)
  val exists = Files.exists(windows)
  printf("file path [%s]\n",posixPath )
  printf("cygpath   [%s]\n",cyg)
  printf("windows   [%s]\n",windows)
  if( exists ){
    printf("exists  [%s] # visible to jvm-based programs\n",exists)
  } else {
    printf("exists  [%s] # NOT visible to jvm-based programs\n",exists)
  }
  val realpath = if( exists ){
    if( Files.isSymbolicLink(windows) ){
      Files.readSymbolicLink(windows)
    } else {
      windows.toRealPath()
    }
  }
  printf("real windows [%s]\n",realpath)
  printf("\n")
}
def cygpath(posixPath:String) = {
  import scala.sys.process._
  Seq("cygpath.exe","-m",posixPath).lazyLines_!.mkString("")
}
```

Here's the output from deref.sc as applied to /bin/awk and to ./ls-link.
(we have to pass the windows-visible version of /bin/awk)

```sh
$ deref.sc ls-link
cygpath   [ls-link]
windows   [.\ls-link]
exists  [true] # visible to jvm-based programs
real windows [C:\cygwin64\bin\ls.exe]
$ cd /bin

$ deref.sc awk
file path [awk]
cygpath   [C:/cygwin64/bin/gawk.exe]
windows   [awk]
exists  [true] # visible to jvm-based programs
real windows [C:\cygwin64\bin\awk]
```

So this shows that, although some windows programs (such as CMD.EXE) cannot see c:/cygwin64/bin/awk, others (such as jvm-based programs) can!

My original question was based on the mistaken assumption that windows programs are not able to see these new symlinks, and since that isn't correct, the residual question is:

What are these new symlinks, and how are they created?  Are they really different, or is this perhaps a side-effect of permissions? Running CMD.EXE as administrator seems to make no difference.

I verified that `c:/cygwin64/bin/awk` is also visible from a WSL session, although that's not so surprising given that the jvm can see them.

UPDATE: it seems that, although `/bin/awk` is visible to our program, it isn't considered to be a symbolic link by `java.nio.file.Files.isSymbolicLink()`.  Its contents consist of the string `"!<symlink>gawk.exe"`, so it seems to be an early cygwin implementation of symlinks, before windows provided native symlinks.

It's unremarkable except for being invisible from CMD.EXE.

Comment: `awk` is a plain file with a `System` Windows attribute, and therefore is hidden by default. Use `dir /A` to show hidden files.

Comment: This is cygwin-specific symlink. In Windows, this is just a plain text file containing `!<symlink>gawk.exe\0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why the links are not visible is due to their file Attribute

`S = System` are not visible in CMD by DOS/Windows design,
from CMD, sorry in German, we have:

```
$ cmd
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.450]
(c) 2020 Microsoft Corporation. Alle Rechte vorbehalten.

D:\cygwin64\bin>attrib zipinfo
   S                 D:\cygwin64\bin\zipinfo

D:\cygwin64\bin>dir zipinfo
 Datenträger in Laufwerk D: ist DATA
 Volumeseriennummer: D603-FB6E

 Verzeichnis von D:\cygwin64\bin

Datei nicht gefunden

D:\cygwin64\bin>dir /A:S zipinfo
 Datenträger in Laufwerk D: ist DATA
 Volumeseriennummer: D603-FB6E

 Verzeichnis von D:\cygwin64\bin

19.06.2018  22:17                16 zipinfo
               1 Datei(en),             16 Bytes
               0 Verzeichnis(se), 542.542.495.744 Bytes frei
```

Answer (score 2):

I use GoodSync to synchronize the volume where Cygwin is installed to a NAS. This is triggered by changes and is supposed to work in the background. For some time now (I cannot say when precisely), the Cygwin installer seems to create Windows native links by default (in many cases, not all). Setting a system variable `CYGWIN` to `winsymlinks:lnk` does not seem to help. Setting this in the system-wide bash profile also does not fix the issue.

However, as these links cannot be resolved properly from a Windows application (a link `/etc/alternatives/2to3` points to `/usr/bin/2to3-3.8`), reading them from GoodSync will fail - apart from the fact that they cannot be backed-up. The option "ignore" on symbolic links in GoodSync does not have the desired effect (maybe it only honors real symbolic links, not reparse points - I've reported that bug already).

So, my solution is to watch out for such errors and then run this script with a list of involved paths to fix the links back to the old Cygwin-style .lnk files.

```
#! /bin/bash
CYGWIN=winsymlinks:lnk; export CYGWIN

for file in $* ; do
    if [ -L "$file" ] ; then
    t="`readlink $file`"
    echo "$file: symbolic link -> $t"
    if [ -L "$file.lnk" ] ; then
        echo "   already ok"
    else
        rm "$file"
        ln -s "$t" "$file"
        echo "   fixed"
    fi
    else
    echo "$file: not a link"
    fi
done

exit 0
```

For an initial scan, I ran a `find / -type l -print` over the entire Cygwin installation, filtered out those paths where a .lnk file of the same name existed, and fixed the rest.

In WSL, the same issues exist - except there is no simple solution. Symbolic links are Windows native links and cannot be read if they point to Unix-style paths. There is no alternative representation except resorting to only relative target paths. Those (may) have a chance of being interpreted correctly also by Windows.

Creating file-based 1:1 backups from file systems with such links will remain a challenge.

Answer (score 1):

Cygwin is much, much older than NTFS support for symlinks. Therefore, Cygwin has its own implementation of symlinks, which is essentially just a text file containing the text `!<symlink>gawk.exe` and is terminated by an ASCII `NUL` character.

Comment: there's actually an exclamation point as the first char:   `"!<symlink>gawk.exe"`