# Cygwin: follow symlinks with MinGW fopen/etc

Tags: cygwin, mingw, symlink, symlink-traversal

Problem: I'm writing some code that is portable to Linux and Cygwin (compiled on msys), and the handling of symlinks is different. On Cygwin, if I create a symlink in the normal way, with a default Cygwin shell (ie. the `CYGWIN` envvar not set):

```
$ ln -s foo bar
```

then `fopen(bar)` doesn't follow the symlink. The first line of text appears to be `!<symlink>.` and my code reports that the opened file isn't UTF-8.

I can fix this by running Cygwin as admin, setting `CYGWIN` to `winsymlinks:nativestrict`, deleting the symlink, and re-creating it. However, this isn't ideal: in my case, the symlinks are created by Subversion from the Linux codebase, so I now need to script the link delete and remake after every update.

1. Is there a better way to do this, or do I have to ask Cygwin users
   to run as admin, and set `CYGWIN`?
2. How do I write code to follow a native Cygwin symlink?
3. How do I write code to find out what type of symlink I'm dealing
   with? This is also asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24222591/6162729), but the answer there is scripted

Thanks.

**Edit**

Ok, I think the answer is basically [here](http://mingw.5.n7.nabble.com/symbolic-links-ln-s-command-tp7159p7171.html), on the MinGW mailing list, from 2007. If you compile with MinGW you can't use Cygwin native symlinks. Maybe the situation has changed since 2007?

Comment: I doubt. Mingw builds vanilla Windows programs, they know nothing of the Cygwin workarounds to build a POSIX system on top of Windows

Comment: Isn't this a windows shortcut? If so, try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22988327/1983398).